# What is the object assigned to a Functional Interface in Java?

Tags: java, functional-interface

*I am new to Lambda Expressions in Java so please don't react too harsh if this question appears silly:*  What is the actual object that gets implemented if I assign it to a `FunctionalInterface`?  I.e., if I do `List<String> lst = new ArrayList<>()` I implement an `ArrayList` object.  What is the object that gets created if I do `Function<String,String> fct = s -> s`?  And is that object immutable, i.e. does it make sense to have a `public static final Function<String,String> REUSE_OFTEN = s -> String.valueOf(s)`?

Comment: You could print out `REUSE_OFTEN.getClass()` and see what its class type is.  My guess is it's something synthesized by the compiler and not part of the API.

Comment: Also, as a general rule of thumb, it's important to note that the keyword `final` doesn’t really achieve immutability for reference types. all it does is stop the field it qualifies from being updated;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I.e., if I do List lst = new ArrayList<>() I implement an
>   ArrayList object.

You instantiate a `ArrayList` rather.

> What is the object that gets created if I do Function
>   fct = s -> s? And is that object immutable, i.e. does it make sense to
>   have a public static final Function REUSE_OFTEN = s ->
>   String.valueOf(s)?

Lambdas are not the same thing than anonymous classes in terms of byte codeand also in terms of behavior/functioning. This last one is close enough but not exactly the same.

Here are two methods that do the same thing, one with lambda the other with anonymous class :

```
public class CompareBoth {

    public void lambda() {
        Function<String,String> fct = s -> s;
        fct.apply("a");
    }


    public void anonymousClass() {
        Function<String,String> fct = new Function<String, String>() {

            @Override
            public String apply(String t) {
                return t;
            }

        };
        fct.apply("a");
    }
}
```

Here the disassembled code :

```
public class cli.CompareBoth {
  public cli.CompareBoth();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return

  public void lambda();
    Code:
       0: invokedynamic #2,  0              // InvokeDynamic #0:apply:()Ljava/util/function/Function;
       5: astore_1
       6: aload_1
       7: ldc           #3                  // String a
       9: invokeinterface #4,  2            // InterfaceMethod java/util/function/Function.apply:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
      14: pop
      15: return

  public void anonymousClass();
    Code:
       0: new           #5                  // class cli/CompareBoth$1
       3: dup
       4: aload_0
       5: invokespecial #6                  // Method cli/CompareBoth$1."<init>":(Lcli/CompareBoth;)V
       8: astore_1
       9: aload_1
      10: ldc           #3                  // String a
      12: invokeinterface #4,  2            // InterfaceMethod java/util/function/Function.apply:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
      17: pop
      18: return
}
```

We can see that the JVM treat them differently.

> What is the actual object that gets implemented ?

As a lambda is created this JVM instruction is performed :

> 0: invokedynamic #2,  0              // InvokeDynamic
>         #0:apply:()Ljava/util/function/Function;

`InvokeDynamic` that was introduced in Java 7 is specified as a bytecode instruction that facilitates the implementation of dynamic languages (for the JVM) through dynamic method invocation.
You can read [this javaworld page](https://www.javaworld.com/article/2860079/learn-java/invokedynamic-101.html) to have more information.

Now, does it really matter as you develop ? 
In most of cases, it doesn't.
Functional interfaces are functionnaly close to anonymous interfaces with multiple slight differences.
Conceptually, I think that it is acceptable to consider them in this way.

About functional interface immutability :

Functional interfaces may have a state but are designed to be immutable.

So you can reuse them if it makes sense.
But `InvokeDynamic` may be optimized by JVM.
So you should not reuse them in your code just to spare some objects.
Instead of, extract the functional interface in a constant or a variable because it makes things more clear or it avoids duplication.

Comment: Should we say that lambdas capturing local variables are also stateless?

Comment: @tsolakp Very good remark. Thanks :)

Comment: Thank you very much for this extensive explanation.

Comment: You are welcome. Thanks for the quick accept :)

Answer (score 2):

When you write a lambda expression -

```
Function<String,String> fct = s -> s;
```

It simply creates an anonymous class that implements `Function<String, String>` interface and overrides its only method `apply()` with the implementation you have provided by `s -> s`. And assign this object to `Function<String, String>` reference.

```
Function<String,String> fct = new Function<>() {
    @Override
    public String apply(String s) {
        return s;
    }
};
```

And it is an immutable object and it does make sense to have a `public static final Function<String,String> REUSE_OFTEN = s -> String.valueOf(s)` as you can reuse same object to apply this operation with the different input.

Comment: Initially, the lambda's body will be desugaed into a static method. After that, at run-time, the wrapper class will be generated for this method. In terms of JVM it's not an anonymous class...

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation.